# When installing on a RAID array, should SWAP space be spread across disks?

Tags: linux, partitioning, memory, raid

I'm installing Debian on a RAID5 array with 4 disks. If this were one big disk, I would create 16GB SWAP partition. Since it is a RAID with 4 disks, I am wondering should I create one 16GB SWAP partition on one disk? or 4 x 4GB SWAP partitions, one on each disk?

I've been searching around but can't find a straight answer.

Comment: I believe (but don't know for certain) you should only have one swap partition, even if it is distributed across your raid array. This question is regarding Raid 1, but I think it answers some of your questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/245976/should-swap-and-raid-1-mix#:~:text=You%20should%20(probably)%20not%20take,already%20using%20a%20RAID%201

Comment: On a RAID array you don't get to choose which data goes on which disks. All the data goes on all the disks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
RAID5 (md0 or whatever)
 |
 `--lvm (on top of the RAID5)
    |
    +-- / (within the lvm)
    |
    `-- swap (within the lvm)
```

It's complex to do in the Debian installer but possible.

This will protect your swap partition from a drive failure, which is important because sudden disappearance of swap due to a drive or other error will make your system crash.

Comment: Can you elaborate any more on how to do this exactly? I created an LVM on the raid, but then I was not able to create `/` or swap on the LVM. I had to abort the install.